# Using Swift Framework in Project with Mixed Swift and Obj-C causes linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, linker

My iOS applicaiton is written in almost entirely in Obj-C, and we recently enabled Swift to be used in the project as well. My framework I created was written entirely in Swift and was working in the application *until* we enabled Swift in the main project and started trying to use my Framework in Swift files in the application.

I am getting a linker error when attempting to build the application. The linker error fails to find a framework that is apart of my Framework and *not* the application itself.

My Framework has all the archs required and worked before we started using the framework in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "Library Search Paths" and "Header Search Paths" in Targets >> Build Settings.